# Fedora 25 Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) as Unable to install Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux

I did just upgrade to Fedora 25. I have installed VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.10_112026_fedora25-1.x86_64.rpm from the official website. However when I try to install Guest OS, I get

[image: the error message]

I did try to run the /sbin/vboxconfig as being asked. I've got

[image]

***Update: I have noticed that the SELinux was showing this message**

```
SELinux is preventing vboxdrv.sh from create access on the file vbox-install.log.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that vboxdrv.sh should be allowed create access on the vbox-install.log file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'vboxdrv.sh' --raw | audit2allow -M my-vboxdrvsh
# semodule -X 300 -i my-vboxdrvsh.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
Target Objects                vbox-install.log [ file ]
Source                        vboxdrv.sh
Source Path                   vboxdrv.sh
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          X260
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-224.fc25.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     X260
Platform                      Linux X260 4.8.8-300.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 15
                              18:10:06 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   3
First Seen                    2016-11-27 15:05:07 GMT
Last Seen                     2016-11-27 16:29:29 GMT
Local ID                      07b1a9aa-ab4c-4db1-97ae-62b46f32a9ec

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1480264169.261:175): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=1545 comm="vboxdrv.sh" name="vbox-install.log" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0


Hash: vboxdrv.sh,init_t,var_log_t,file,create
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by disabling UEFI secureboot.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/chap-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-System_Configuration.html#sect-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-System_Configuration-Enter

Comment: Can you go into more detail on how you resolved this? This is in case the URL is removed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same SElinux notification and bash response when I attempted a vBox install on FED25. Check YUM and ensure the kernel-devel is installed to facilitate modification of the kernel-core. Once I installed the kernel-devel the 'rcvboxdrv setup' command in the vBox manual (see section 2.3) installed the drivers and vBox was able to boot.

Comment: I have the kernel-devel already installed.